# How can I save the value of a custom field to wordpress' user_meta after altering it with javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, database, wordpress

I'm using a plugin to create fields in user_meta inside WordPress database.
To create a page, first I created a Template. Then I asked for the fields' value with the plugin's function:

```
<?php $pc = rp_user_data_func("pc","1"); ?>
```

Then I used javascript to convert the PHP variable to javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> var pc = <?php echo $pc; ?>;</script>
```

And finally used the variable `pc` in several javascript functions, which will change the value of the variable.

Now I need to update the custom field and save the new value in the WordPress' database, once the user clicks in a "save" button.

Is there is a specific way to do it in WordPress? 
That's a simplified version of the code:

```
<?php
    $pc = rp_user_data_func("pc","1");
    if ( empty($pc) ) $pc = '0';

    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        myfnc();
        }
        function myfnc()
        {
            $user_id = 1;
            add_user_meta( $user_id , $pc , $pp , false );
        }
        ?>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
    var pc = <?php echo $pc; ?>;

    function pc_add () {
            pc = pc + 1;
            alert(pc);
        }
        function pc_sub () {
            pc = pc - 1;
            alert(pc);
        }
        </script>
        <style> 
            .square_add{
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;
                Background-color: green;
                float: left;
            }
            .square_sub{
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;
                Background-color: red;
                float: left;
            }
        </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="square_add" onclick="pc_add();">ADD</div>
            <div class="square_sub" onclick="pc_sub();">SUB</div>
            <form action="." method="post">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">              
        </form>
        </body>
</html>
```

Here is the page with this code working (changing the variable but not saving): http://www.anastorm.ihostfull.com/teste/

Comment: Show us your form solution code and explain what did not work.

Comment: Updated the question with the code to be easier to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just got help.

Here is the code working if anyone has the same problem:

```
<?php 
$pc = rp_user_data_func("pc", "1");
if (empty($pc))
    $pc = '0';

function myfnc($pc2) {
$user_id = 1;
update_user_meta($user_id, 'pc', $pc2);
$pct = rp_user_data_func("pc", "1");
unset($_POST);
}

if (isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['pc'])) {
myfnc($_POST['pc']);
}
?>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var pc = <?php echo $pc; ?>;

        function pc_add() {
            pc = pc + 1;
            alert(pc);
            document.getElementById('pc').setAttribute('value',pc);
        }
        function pc_sub() {
            pc = pc - 1;
            alert(pc);
            document.getElementById('pc').setAttribute('value',pc);
        }
    </script>
    <style> 
        .square_add{ width: 100px; height: 100px; Background-color: green; float: left;}
        .square_sub{ width: 100px; height: 100px; Background-color: red; float: left;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="square_add" onclick="pc_add();">ADD</div>
    <div class="square_sub" onclick="pc_sub();">SUB</div>
    <form action="." method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="pc" id="pc" value="" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">          
    </form>
</body>
```